# web scraping from google page no longer returns anything

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

The below Excel vba code use to work and return the market cap, 52 week low and current price into my spreadsheet. It no longer does though and cannot work out why. Class names haven't changed but the `getElementsByClassName` doesn't seem to return anything anymore I think.

```
Sub get_title_header()

    Dim wb As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim allElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
    sURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=aapl+stock+quote"
    
    wb.navigate sURL
    wb.Visible = False
    
    While wb.Busy
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    Set doc = wb.document.body
    
    On Error GoTo err_clear
      
    Set allElements = doc.getElementsByClassName("iyjjgb")
    x = allElements(3).innerText
     Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = x
    x = allElements(8).innerText
     Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = x
    x = ""
    x = allElements(0).innerText
     Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = x
    x = ""
    
err_clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
    End If
    wb.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Maybe plot the Err.number and description and not only clear it.

Comment: Also, print the response status code and check that

Comment: If you try it manually, you will see that the URL no longer works with IE. It opens Edge. IE is dead and no longer supported.

Comment: I don't get an error.

Comment: @Zwenn you make a very good point. I had forgotten about this. How do I get around it? I am not aware that I can use Edge for this.

Comment: The only browser that could be controlled directly from VBA was IE. If it only works with a browser, then the only thing left is SeleniumBasic and the WebDriver for Chrome or Edge and the corresponding browser. Without a browser it might work via XML HTTP Request (xhr). For this, it must be possible to access the desired content directly. xhr does not execute JS, so no dynamic content.